# can we make exceptions(thrown from DAO methods) eligible for Spring DataAccessException without using @Repository annotation in DAO

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, dao, spring-aop

what if i don't annotate DAO classes with @Repository, will that still  makes the unchecked exceptions (thrown from DAO methods)  eligible for translation into Spring DataAccessException?? Can anyone expain this? bit confused with @Repository annotation

Answer (score 0):

Definition of @Repository given on this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html)

> Indicates that an annotated class is a "Repository", originally
> defined by Domain-Driven Design (Evans, 2003) as "a mechanism for
> encapsulating storage, retrieval, and search behavior which emulates a
> collection of objects".
>
> Teams implementing traditional J2EE patterns such as "Data Access
> Object" may also apply this stereotype to DAO classes, though care
> should be taken to understand the distinction between Data Access
> Object and DDD-style repositories before doing so. This annotation is
> a general-purpose stereotype and individual teams may narrow their
> semantics and use as appropriate.
>
> A class thus annotated is eligible for Spring [DataAccessException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html)
> translation when used in conjunction with a
> [PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.html). The annotated class is
> also clarified as to its role in the overall application architecture
> for the purpose of tooling, aspects, etc.

**what if I don't annotate DAO classes with @Repository, will that still
makes the unchecked exceptions (thrown from DAO methods) eligible for translation into Spring DataAccessException??**

No,Because as per details given on this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.html)

> Bean post-processor that automatically applies persistence exception
> translation to any bean marked with Spring's @Repository annotation,
> adding a corresponding PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor to the
> exposed proxy (either an existing AOP proxy or a newly generated proxy
> that implements all of the target's interfaces).

Hope this will help you understand!!